# Problemas com auth::routes

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estou tendo problema com `Auth::routes()` utilizo o framework `Laravel` na versão `5.2` meu arquivo de rotas está assim:

```
Route::singularResourceParameters();
Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => ['cors']], function (){
  Route::resource('clientes', 'ClienteController');
  Route::resource('categorias', 'CategoriaController');
  Route::resource('embalagens', 'EmbalagemController');
  Route::resource('tipo_produtos', 'TipoProdutoController');
  Route::resource('subcategorias', 'SubCategoriaController');
  Route::resource('produtos', 'ProdutoController');
  Route::resource('loteproduto', 'LoteProdutoController');
});

Route::get('/', [
  'uses' => 'Dashboard@index',
  'as' => 'dashboard.index'
]);
```

e em meus `controllers` adicionei este construtor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

> Quando tento entrar em alguma página acontesce este erro:
>   call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard' does not have a method 'routes'

O que pode ser isto ?

Answer (score 3):

Achei o problema, o que acontesce é que tenho trabalhado com o framework de várias versões por este motivo fiz uma confusão na hora de utilizar o comando.

na versão `5.3` é:

```
Auth::routes();
```

ja na versão `5.2` que é a questão é assim:

```
Route::auth();
```

Solucionando meu problema.